# On Magento 1.9 https only broke my site

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I saw my site was checking out over http not https, so I went to config settings and under the web tab, I entered https to both secure and unsecure.

Turns out my ssl has expired and now my entire site is down, front and back end. How do I revert the settings if I can't access back end?

Comment: check phpmyadmin in your db core_config_data table it http:// or https://

Comment: Would altering the .htaccess file fix my problem?

Comment: No, you have to change the base url configuration in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following SQL query in your database (for example in phpmyadmin) to revert the change:

```
update core_config_data set value=replace(value,'https','http') where path like '%base_url';
```

If you use table prefixes, add this prefix to `core_config_data` accordingly.

Comment: ....perfect....

Answer (score 0):

If your ssl certificate is expired it doesn't mean your site is offline.
You can bypass the browser warning on expired certificate  and login to your site.

Comment: Turns out there was never ssl installed on the site, so it through a page not found error